# Aplicação WPF. Como fazer referência a imagem no código XAML, para que outro usuário possa visualizá-las ao executar arquivo .exe do projeto?

Tags: c#, xaml

Estou tendo um problema com a minha aplicação WPF. Eu tenho duas imagens no código XAML, e quando eu executo a aplicação no meu computador, elas aparecem normal, mas quando eu pedir a alguém para executar o arquivo .exe , ela roda normalmente, só que as imagens não aparecem. Como posso fazer para definir as imagens de origem para que, quando outro usuário executar o arquivo .exe , as imagens apareçam na tela?

O código da imagem no XAML:

```
<Image Source="\MULINFSV0005\User$\mathias.deitos\Meus Documentos\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\clock.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="41,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68"/>
```

Comment: Isso te ajuda? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636047/image-in-wpf-button-not-visible-at-runtime

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: ainda não, tentei seguir os passos do link mas meu problema é um pouco diferente, quando eu rodo a aplicação as imagens aparecem, mas quando eu passo o executável para outra pessoa testar, as imagens não aparecem

Comment: O seu problema é exatamente aquele. Porque a imagem não está sendo colocada como *resource*. Tá cheio de referências ensinando fazer assim: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2416464/221800

Comment: Que legal, você disse que aquela resposta não te ajudou. Quando alguém postou exatamente ela, você aceitou a resposta.

Comment: é que na real, eu tentei fazer exatamente como no exemplo que o cara respondeu, tirei todo o caminho e deixei somente o nome da imagem. Ele foi bem direto na resposta. Mas valeu bigown, só me entendi melhor na resposta dele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

Caso tenha uma pasta com as imagens dentro use assim:

```
<Image Source="Imagens\start.png" />
```

Caso sua imagem esteja marcada como `resource` use desta maneira:

```
<Image Source="Logo.png" />
```

Os dois exemplos acima são atalhos para:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Logo.png" />
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Imagens\start.png" />
```